# Append Text to Shape Without Overwriting Existing Text in VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a script in VBA that prints out certain user selected variables to a PPT template. In this sub:

```
Private Sub WarningInfo()
Call Dictionary.WarningInfo

  'Sets the font for the warning information text.

   With ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("WarningText1").TextFrame2.TextRange.Font

    .Size = 24
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .Shadow.Visible = True

   End With

ComboBoxList = Array(CStr(ComboBox3))

   For Each Ky In ComboBoxList

   'On Error Resume Next
   'If nothing is selected in ComboBox3, do nothing and exit this sub.
    If ComboBox3 = "" Then
    Exit Sub
    'Otherwise, if it has a selection, insert selected text.
    Else
     ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("WarningText1").TextFrame2.TextRange = vbCrLf & dict2.Item(Ky)(0)

    End If

 Next

Set dict2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

It will print out dict2.Item(Ky)(0) within the shape WarningText1. This variable is selected by the user in a GUI and it is pulled from a dictionary. An example of what would be selected and output is "No hail expected".

My next sub is this:

```
Private Sub WarningInfo2()
Call Dictionary.WindInfo

  'Sets the font for the warning information text.

   With ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("WarningText1").TextFrame2.TextRange.Font

    .Size = 24
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .Shadow.Visible = True

   End With

ComboBoxList = Array(CStr(ComboBox4))

   For Each Ky In ComboBoxList

   'On Error Resume Next
   'If nothing is selected in ComboBox4, do nothing and exit this sub.
    If ComboBox4 = "" Then
    Exit Sub
    'Otherwise, if it has a selection, insert selected text.
    Else
     ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("WarningText1").TextFrame2.TextRange = vbCrLf & dict3.Item(Ky)(0)

    End If

 Next

Set dict3 = Nothing

End Sub
```

It will print out dict3.Item(Ky)(0). However, with the way this second sub is set up, it will just overwrite the data from the first sub (since both subs are within the same UserForm). I need to find a way to change this line of code `ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("WarningText1").TextFrame2.TextRange = vbCrLf & dict3.Item(Ky)(0)` so that it ADDS this text to the existing text within the shape "WarningText1".

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Comment: ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("WarningText1").TextFrame2.TextRange = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("WarningText1").TextFrame2.TextRange & vBCrLf & dict3.Item(Ky) (0)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! If you add it as an answer, I will mark it as the correct solution.

Comment: Done. Glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("WarningText1").TextFrame2.TextRange = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("WarningText1").TextFrame2.TextRange & vBCrLf & dict3.Item(Ky) (0)